# How do I create a data frame pairing people to numbers and other elements using rows and columns?

Tags: r

How can I pair people with names (Pat, David, Allen, Annie, and Tim) with a number ID 1-5, a grade of one of these numbers (79.5, 98, 83.3, 98.8, and 80.3), and their sex (M or F)? It doesn't matter who gets which number or sex except that Annie must be paired with F and the rest with M.

I tried to pair them to these values but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you store each of the things you want in a vector then you can make a data frame where each entry is a person with a grade and sex. For example:

```
people <- c("Pat", "David", "Allen", "Annie", "Tim")
grades <- c(79.5, 98, 83.3, 98.8, 80.3)
sex <- as.factor(c('M','M','M','F','M'))

data.frame(people, grades, sex)
```